# XSD to dataset (Which also is a xsd?)

Tags: c#, xml, crystal-reports, xsd, dataset

I'm a little confused, I have a XSD that states the structure of a XML I have already generated and filled, now I have to display its information in a PDF.

I was thinking about crystal reports but I don't if it's the best solution, but well, I have read that I can create a crystal report from my XSD but then I have to instantiate the XSD to fill it, but the XSD I have is not a dataset it's a XML Schema so I don't know what to do, I'm pretty lost down here.

This is the XSD scheme I got (Is a public file from the government): http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv32.xsd

And this is a sample XML I have generated with it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cfdi:Comprobante xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv32.xsd" version="3.2" fecha="2012-05-22T17:47:38" sello="G3xkr9rKA8ix0ub8XJTNqb0TRR14Sxs4Uj7oDfPj8oCM4HzoMTF7pWcpfx5VCzp9rT+CW6IstoiYLaUNiBtDwCS8oHrYuVawPh+tn+GQpSNi+plafJjcOq8U8wl0nk1hKnqhJWenklCRgxNOFvVeYIMLe0MycUU/2Q7g0mgJOhw=" formaDePago="Pago en una sola exhibicion" noCertificado="30001000000100000800" certificado="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" subTotal="105.5678" total="1000" tipoDeComprobante="ingreso" metodoDePago="Efectivo" LugarExpedicion="Madereria Central">
  <cfdi:Emisor rfc="PEPJ8001019Q8" nombre="Mader">
    <cfdi:DomicilioFiscal calle="Calle1" noExterior="12" colonia="Industrial" localidad="Mexico" referencia="aqui" municipio="df" estado="df" pais="mexico" codigoPostal="07300" />
    <cfdi:RegimenFiscal Regimen="Persona Moral" />
  </cfdi:Emisor>
  <cfdi:Receptor rfc="DUK" nombre="Elevadores">
    <cfdi:Domicilio calle="8" noExterior="8" noInterior="0" colonia="9" localidad="9" referencia="9" municipio="9" estado="9" pais="9" codigoPostal="9" />
  </cfdi:Receptor>
  <cfdi:Conceptos>
    <cfdi:Concepto cantidad="1" unidad="metros" noIdentificacion="A1121212" descripcion="Ayacahuitle Primera" valorUnitario="500" importe="500" />
    <cfdi:Concepto cantidad="2" unidad="metros" noIdentificacion="A21128142" descripcion="Ayacahuitle Sec" valorUnitario="600" importe="1200" />
    <cfdi:Concepto cantidad="3" unidad="metros" noIdentificacion="A31281" descripcion="Ayacahuitle Ter" valorUnitario="700" importe="2100" />
  </cfdi:Conceptos>
  <cfdi:Impuestos>
    <cfdi:Retenciones>
      <cfdi:Retencion impuesto="IVA" importe="100" />
    </cfdi:Retenciones>
  </cfdi:Impuestos>
  <cfdi:Complemento>
    <tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/TimbreFiscalDigital/TimbreFiscalDigital.xsd" selloCFD="G3xkr9rKA8ix0ub8XJTNqb0TRR14Sxs4Uj7oDfPj8oCM4HzoMTF7pWcpfx5VCzp9rT+CW6IstoiYLaUNiBtDwCS8oHrYuVawPh+tn+GQpSNi+plafJjcOq8U8wl0nk1hKnqhJWenklCRgxNOFvVeYIMLe0MycUU/2Q7g0mgJOhw=" FechaTimbrado="2012-05-22T17:47:42" UUID="221BA53A-827A-4474-B9F9-3542ECDEB979" noCertificadoSAT="30001000000100000801" version="1.0" selloSAT="ZnKdULidoo95wXOmk1cPM/ZB5Fh8PvsbkRD+zgTA21yIBqjFopt4UGL6sA0DqeWJdzI1Q92lxm6FwrlK+GxFHM7fvKeStE5elEsCW4GyVQG7gvXXxTKiM0xxPzTkxh6OQLeqDMgzodM0my/M8KJx/JiT8JeEVu4wZF1cyc1w13k=" />
  </cfdi:Complemento>
</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

Comment: What is your data set?  DataTable? XML? Can you post some code?

Comment: Of course, I have added the XSD I got, and a sample XML, now I have to present the XML into a PDF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to answer your question considering the tags you've used... and some guessing.

Since you've mentioned C# and Crystal Reports... Visual Studio comes with the free edition of Crystal Reports. It does what you need, and it's free: has a graphical designer to build the output layout; comes with a free viewer you can embed if your users need to see the result before exporting or printing, and has an API if you need to generate it programatically.

Your confusion with XSD and Dataset probably comes from not understanding how Crystal Reports sources its data. Try [this link](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Using-Crystal-Reports.aspx), or any other when searching for "crystal reports push method".

In a nutshell, with the push method, at design time in Visual Studio you use a Dataset as a data source for the Crystal Report so that you can drag and drop to source and format your report's content. At run time, you populate a dataset with report data and then set that as the report's data source. Since you can populate the dataset from XML, you now have a solution.

To convert your XSD you posted to an XSD that Visual Studio will recognized it as a "dataset" XSD, try this and inspect the generated output to understand the difference between the two:

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.ProhibitDtd = false;
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"D:\temp 1\sitio_internet\cfd\3\cfdv32.xsd", settings))
{
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();            
    dataSet.ReadXmlSchema(reader);  
    dataSet.WriteXmlSchema(@"D:\temp 1\sitio_internet\cfd\3\cfdv32-DS.xsd");
}
```

As a learning tool, add both XSDs to a Visual Studio project; for each of the XSDs, right click and invoke ***View Designer*** command. You'll see for one an XSD editor; for the other, a data set diagram...

This should take care of the XSD to dataset thing.

What @paquetp didn't tell you, is that even if you're (really) lucky to get good and cheap support for XSL-FO on .NET (since you've mentioned C#), you're still in need for something to easily edit your stylesheet; most people prefer WYSIWYG editors for this, which is another thing that's hard to find cheap.

So I would think that given the XSD you posted, which allows to create a DataSet from it, the approach with Crystal Reports could work with some nice, user friendly features.

Answer (score 2):

The technology you are looking for is [XSL-FO](http://www.w3schools.com/xslfo/)

Comment: This allows me to format the resulting PDF? I need to make a "PDF model" in which I can arrange the fields of the XML, and also add some pther fields not contained in the XML like Logos, Telephone numbers, QRcodes. etc

Comment: Basically, yes.  You'll need a vendor - I've used Apache FOP in the past. http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/index.html

Comment: Typically you use XSLT to convert the XML into the XSL Formatting Objects markup vocabulary, and then you use an XSL-FO rendering engine such as FOP to convert this to PDF. This can be a fairly labour-intensive process. You might find tools that can make it easier (I don't know about the one you cite in Crystal Reports).

Comment: @MichaelKay - thanks, I failed to mention that step.  I was thinking since it sounds like he would need to move his XML to a Dataset that isn't done yet, sticking with just XML might be better than importing his data into a db and using other reporting tools.  Andres, if you do want to dump your xml into a Dataset, you could use the .net XSD schema definition tool: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.80).aspx